# Building a Dockerfile with RUN update-ca-certificates fails for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core

I'm trying to build my ASP.NET Core application with the following `Dockerfile` on Docker Hub:

```docker
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim-arm32v7
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
WORKDIR /app

COPY src/JoplinAsustorMediator/root_CA_mu88.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root_CA_mu88.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/JoplinAsustorMediator/JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj", "src/JoplinAsustorMediator/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/JoplinAsustorMediator/JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/JoplinAsustorMediator"
RUN dotnet build "JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "JoplinAsustorMediator.dll"]
```

On Docker Hub, applying my custom Root CA fails with `The command '/bin/sh -c update-ca-certificates' returned a non-zero code: 1`. This is the complete log output:

```docker
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.3' to the list of known hosts.
Switched to a new branch 'release'
Pulling cache layers for index.docker.io/mu88/joplinasustormediator:latest...
Done!
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'19.03.8', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2020-03-11T01:24:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.40', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'afacb8b7f0', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.12.17'}}, {u'Version': u'1.2.13', u'Name': u'containerd', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429'}}, {u'Version': u'1.0.0-rc10', u'Name': u'runc', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd'}}, {u'Version': u'0.18.0', u'Name': u'docker-init', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'fec3683'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2020-03-11T01:24:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.40
Platform: {u'Name': u'Docker Engine - Community'}
Version: 19.03.8
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: afacb8b7f0
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.12.17
Starting build of index.docker.io/mu88/joplinasustormediator:latest...
Step 1/18 : ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim-arm32v7
Step 2/18 : FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
---> 0d95d6c17320
Step 3/18 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 8dd3a3b6f379
Step 4/18 : COPY src/JoplinAsustorMediator/root_CA_mu88.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root_CA_mu88.crt
---> bf7737d82c09
Step 5/18 : RUN update-ca-certificates
---> Running in 4af1b887f715
[91mstandard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
[0m
Removing intermediate container 4af1b887f715
The command '/bin/sh -c update-ca-certificates' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

When running the command `docker build -f .\src\JoplinAsustorMediator\Dockerfile -t joppi .` locally on my laptop, the image can be built and the output looks like this:

```docker
[+] Building 37.9s (20/20) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 874B
 => [internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 35B
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim-arm32v7
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0@sha256:85ea9832ae26c70618418cf7c699186776ad066d88770fd6fd1edea9b260379a
 => [internal] load build context
 => => transferring context: 17.80kB
 => [base 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.5-buster-slim-arm32v7@sha256:7e999a0e31ef05bfbec335d4ded2f16c316ec6a9d8cd05d4590ab6f469493900
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [src/JoplinAsustorMediator/JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj, src/JoplinAsustorMediator/]
 => CACHED [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "src/JoplinAsustorMediator/JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj"
 => [base 3/4] COPY src/JoplinAsustorMediator/root_CA_mu88.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root_CA_mu88.crt
 => [build 5/7] COPY . . 
 => [base 4/4] RUN update-ca-certificates
 => [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/src/JoplinAsustorMediator
 => [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
 => [publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish "JoplinAsustorMediator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
 => [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app
 => [final 2/2] COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
 => exporting to image
 => => exporting layers
 => => writing image sha256:6bd051cc170c8c82ed1385a7ca9f35f657b28861deb7c0865412922e9429f695
 => => naming to docker.io/library/joppi
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any obvious error?

**Update 26.04.2021: When not including the custom Root CA into the image but copying the certificate into a running container and calling `update-ca-certificates` within the container, it works as expected. Of course, this is not a solution because I don't want to do this for each and every container.**

Comment: try running `update-ca-certificates` in the image

Comment: @Ashok how do I do that? Or do you mean to remove `RUN update-ca-certificates` from the `Dockerfile` and execute it manually in the container?

Comment: @Ashok Please see the today's update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The key part of the output is this: `exec user process caused "exec format error"`. This is related to architecture mismatch. The build machine is amd64 and the arch of your Dockerfile is arm32. For whatever reason, it looks like Docker Hub's build doesn't like to use emulation. You can get this same behavior by using `arm32v7/debian:buster-slim` and running `update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: @MattThalman Ah interesting! And in which way do I have to modify my `Dockerfile` so that the build machine will be `arm32` as well? Or do I have to set this on Docker Hub and not in the `Dockerfile`?